# If condition and empty variable

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, boolean

I have this code:

```
If(!isset($a) || empty($a))
{
    // code to run when $a not set or empty;
}
Elseif ($a==0)
{
     //code to run when $a is equal 0
}
Else
{
      //code to run in all other scenarios
}
```

The issue is that when $a is equal 0 then empty($a) is true and the first code runs. I need the second one to run. How do I do it?

Comment: Well, what exactly *is* the condition? What do you want to test for exactly?

Comment: i want to see if the $a is set, if it is, run the first code. If it's empty (that means empty string or set to nothing) run the first code. If it's equal to 0, run the second code, if it's anything else (negative or positive number) run the third code. Don't understand why it's not understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if((!isset($a) || empty($a)) && $a !== 0)
{
    // code runs when $a not set or empty and $a is not 0;
}
elseif ($a === 0)
{
     //code runs when $a is equal 0
}
else
{
      //code runs in all other scenarios
}
```

**Update:**
Changed to typesafe comparison.

Comment: This didn't work either. If I set $a="" the second code runs, even though i want it the first one to run. It seems like in PHP $a="" and $a=0 is the same.

Comment: I found the solution and your answer was the closest and inspired me to try what I tried. If you modify yours (add the equal signs) to match mine I'll accept your answer

Comment: That's right - it's better to use the typesafe comparison in this case. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (isset($a) && $a == 0)
    {
    //code to run when $a is equal 0
    }
elseif (empty($a))
    {
    // code to run when $a not set or empty;
    }
else
    {
    //code to run in all other scenarios
    }
```

Comment: I was getting excited about this one. But when i tried it, it didn't work. When you set $a="" the first code runs, even though the second one would be expected to run

Comment: @user2395238, what? I see that your logic completely different than your code. Please, update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

replace this and try

```
If(!isset($a) || $a=='') 
{
// code to run when $a not set or empty;
}
Elseif ($a==0)
{
     //code to run when $a is equal 0
}
Else
{
      //code to run in all other scenarios
}
```

Comment: You cannot replace `empty` with `$a==''`

Comment: Why? empty and blank both are same in my knowlage. may you tell me reason why i am cannot replace.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I set $a=0 the first condition evaluates as TRUE and that is because $a=='' is true. I just tested it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
if (!isset($a) || (empty($a) && $a!==0))
{
    //run code if $a is not set or is empty
}
elseif ($a===0)
{
    //run code if $a is 0;
}
else
{
    //all other scenarios
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Empty function returns false when 0 (0 as an integer).

So your code should be

```
If(!isset($a))
{
    // code to run when $a not set or empty;
}
Elseif ($a==0)
{
     //code to run when $a is equal 0
}
Else
{
      //code to run in all other scenarios
}
```

Comment: [empty](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) return false when the value is 0 as a string or an integer

Comment: Empty string have to be considered as empty. In your case it would be *all other scenarios*